# Development of Django project, code exception, automatically locate the exception to the code segment after the project is overloaded

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

Question:
This is the case, I use VsCode to develop Django projects,
I haven't finished writing a piece of code, but due to my operating habits, I will often ctrl + s, or the automatic save function provided by Vscode will save my code.

At this time, the running Django project will be automatically reloaded, and because my code is not finished, reloading Django will definitely throw an exception, and Vscode will automatically locate the page where I wrote the code at this time. Where is the code segment where the exception occurs.

Originally, I was happily writing code, and suddenly the page jumped to another location, which was terrible and greatly affected my development.

I just switched from pycharm to vscode. This problem has affected me for several days. If it can’t be solved, I can’t use vscode to develop happily.

I hope that vscode will not help me locate in my editing interface, it is enough to throw an exception in the terminal below.

Friends who know the solution, please feel free to enlighten me~~~
Thank you

My troubleshooting process:
I tried my best to find the various settings of vscode, but I couldn't find the corresponding configuration

I only kept the Python and Django 2 vscode plugins, and determined that this problem is not caused by other plugins

Thanks again to friends who are willing to help me, and friends who are thinking about my problem, thank you.

[Screenshot Video Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQcag.gif)

Comment: Forget to say:
Vscode version: 1.52.0
Operating system: manjaro